# c++ bad_weak_ptr error

Tags: c++, boost

I want to create some `Timer` class, which prints "text" every N seconds, where N will be initialized in constructor.

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>

#include <iostream>

class Timer : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Timer>
{
public:
    Timer ( const double interval ) : interval_sec( interval )
    {
        io_service_ = new boost::asio::io_service;
        timer_      = new boost::asio::deadline_timer ( * io_service_ );
        start( );
        io_service_ -> run( );
    }

    void start ( )
    {
        timer_ -> expires_from_now( boost::posix_time::seconds( 0 ) );
        timer_ -> async_wait(boost::bind( &Timer::handler
                                        , shared_from_this( )
                                        , boost::asio::placeholders::error
                                        )
                            );
    }

private:
    void handler( const boost::system::error_code& error )
    {
        if ( error )
        {
            std::cerr << error.message( ) << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        printf( "text\n" );
        timer_ -> expires_from_now( boost::posix_time::seconds( interval_sec ) );
        timer_ -> async_wait( boost::bind( &Timer::handler
                                         , shared_from_this( )
                                         , boost::asio::placeholders::error
                                         )
                            );
    }

private:
    boost::asio::io_service * io_service_;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer * timer_;
    double interval_sec;
};

int main()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<Timer> timer( new Timer ( 10 ) );
    return 0;
}
```

But I have `bad_weak_ptr` error.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_weak_ptr> >'
  what():  tr1::bad_weak_ptr
Aborted
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in your debugger?  I'd guess that `main()` returns before your timer fires, causing `timer` to get destroyed.  Are you sure that `async_wait` holds onto the shared object?

Comment: You might also want to do something about the memory leaks. Creating members with `new` is almost never a good idea.

Comment: A little bit OT in this question, but it's the first result googling for `boost::bad_weak_ptr`, so I'll write this here. A nice `boost::bad_weak_ptr` exception (`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_weak_ptr> >`) is also thrown if one tries to replace `boost::shared_ptr<YourClass>` with `std::shared_ptr<YourClass>`, so watch out. :)

Comment: @Avio this is very good advice and was the cause of my similar problem. Thank you! In particular, don't mix the use of `std::make_shared` with `boost::weak_ptr` in this context.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The problem is most probably that you cannot use `shared_from_this` until the object is actually managed by a shared pointer. In general it is not a good idea to launch a thread or asynchronous service in the constructor, as you might be unlucky and the new thread might start before the constructor has completed and thus execute on a not fully constructed object.

In your particular case it is even worse, as you are entering the event loop inside the constructor of your `Timer` class, and that means that control never returns to `main`, the object is never managed by the `shared_ptr` in main...

You should move the call to `start` and the call to `run()` to a different function, and call that from `main` *after* the object is actually managed in the `shared_ptr`.

Comment: In my opinion it's sort of ugly, that I cannot construct that object and forget about it. I should call it's `start( )` method and so and so on. By the way, can I call `io_service_ -> run( );` in `start( )` function?

Comment: @garmOnboz1a: There is no problem in creating an object and forgetting about it, just not in the way you are doing it: i.e. there is a problem in calling `shared_from_this` before the object is managed in a `shared_ptr`, and the call to `run` will not complete, but rather grab the thread and execute the event loop. You can call the `io_service_->run()` from wherever you want, but it will grab control of the thread and will not return from it until the control loop is exited. And sincerely, I am not sure that it makes sense to do it there.

Comment: From a design point of view, it does not make sense that the `Timer` being only one of the potential classes (and objects) that can be registered for asynchronous interactions grabs the thread in one of its methods. Consider that if `start` does it, then you will not be able to use more than one `Timer` per thread --i.e. each timer will grab it's own thread... You should read a tutorial on asynchronous programming and try to understand the examples and why they are built that way.

Comment: So, if I want to call some object's method (i.e. from main), I should create one thread for `io_service_->run()` (in main too), and join it? In other words, how can I grab control back in `main()`?

Comment: In your code there is a single thread, and you can use it as you please, but `io_service_->run()` will grab it. That means that if you want an instruction to be executed, the `io_service_->run()` cannot be called *before* that instruction.

Answer (score 12):

Before calling `shared_from_this()` your class needs to be stored in a `shared_ptr`.  This means that you cannot call `shared_from_this()` inside the constructor, because the line the object won't be placed into the shared_ptr until after the constructor is finished.

This is the reason that classes which use `enable_shared_from_this` typically have a `start` function which does the final steps of initialization that require the use of `shared_from_this()`.  That start function needs to be called after the object is completely constructed, and so cannot be called from inside the constructor as you are doing.