# Passing shared_ptr of this in constructor

Tags: c++

I have a code like the following

```cpp
class Task;

class Attribute
{
public:
    Attribute(Task* task, std::string name);

    std::shared_ptr<Task> task_;
    std::string name_;
};

class Task : std::enable_shared_from_this<Task>
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Task> getSharedPtr()
    {
        return this->shared_from_this();
    }

    Attribute att1_ = {this, "attribute1"};
    Attribute att2_ = {this, "attribute2"};
};

Attribute::Attribute(Task* task, std::string name)
    : name_(name)
{
   task_ = task->getSharedPtr();
}
```

When I run it I get a

```
$ terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_weak_ptr'
```

from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558734/c-bad-weak-ptr-error) I got that I cannot call `shared_from_this()` untill the object is fully constructed.
I guess this means that I cannot create objects of type `Attribute` in the constructor, but I should instantiate them after the constructor ends.

Do you know if it is a way to overcome this problem, because it would be really annoying for me to have to instantiate the Attribute objects not in the constructor.

Comment: Is the `Task` object managed by `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: why cant you pass `task` as `const std::shared_ptr<Task>&` to your constructor?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're falling foul of this rules, as per [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this):

> Note that prior to calling shared_from_this on an object t, there must
>   be a std::shared_ptr that owns t.

You seem to have a strange ownership relationship between `Task` and `Attribute` which you may want to reconsider (if a `Task` owns its `Attributes`, why do they need `shared_ptr`s to their `Task`?).

Comment: I think you are right, I suppose I just went through a smart pointer frenzy!

Answer (score 1):

Since the `Task` *owns* the `Attribute`s, the `Attribute`s don't need to share ownership with the `Task` - they do not have to worry about outliving the `Task`. You can just use raw pointers:

```
class Attribute
{
public:
    Attribute(Task* task, std::string name);

    Task* task_;
    std::string name_;
};
```

Or, if you want to express the semantic more explicitly, `observer_ptr<Task>`.

Note that you'll have to have a copy/move constructors/assignment operators for `Task` that correctly reassign the attributes to point to the new `Task` instead of the old one.

Answer (score 0):

I got the very same error (on mac) when I forgot "public" in front of std::enable_shared_from_this.